# SECURE Connection to GCP VM Instance and pull files out

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, instance

This is a similar question - [How to connect and access Google Cloud Compute Engine VM via Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393887/how-to-connect-and-access-google-cloud-compute-engine-vm-via-python-3-6)

I have two projects **A** and **B**

I would like to run python script on VM from project **B** and well and **locally** to connect to VM on project **A** and full list of files from folder `/test/`

Ideally by using Google API not third party packages like -  https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/

Comment: There is some lak on detail: do you need to access to the VM by the private IP or the public is enough? Do you want to access from the shell command? Through an app? If so, in which language? Is it for getting files from the VM in the project A? or do you need a SSH access for doing more than copying files?

Answer (score 0):

There is an official [Python client library](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#google_apis_python_client_library) for GCP but a connection to an instance is not supported with the APIs.

What you can do is use [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) that can be installed on any instance and your local machine.

In particular the command to connect is:

```
gcloud compute ssh EXAMPLE-INSTANCE --zone=ZONE
```

Before running the command from your local machine yo have to [authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) into project A.

Finally to connect from instance in Project B to your instance in project A

```
gcloud compute ssh EXAMPLE-INSTANCE --zone=ZONE --project=PROJECT-B
```