# How do you SSH into a Google Compute Engine VM instance with Python rather than the CLI?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-api-client

I want to SSH into a GCE VM instance using the `google-api-client`. I am able to start an instance using `google-api-client` with the following code:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
project = 'my_project'  
zone = 'us-west2-a'  
instance = 'my_instance' 
request = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
response = request.execute()
```

In the command line the above code is rendered as:

```
gcloud compute instances start my_instance
```

Similarly, to SSH into a GCE VM instance with the command line one writes:

```
gcloud init && gcloud compute ssh my_instance --project my_project --verbosity=debug --zone=us-west2-a
```

I've already got the SSH keys set up and all that.

I want to know how to write the above command line in Google Api Client or Python.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official REST API method to connect to a Compute Engine instance with SSH. But assuming you have the SSH keys configured as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools), in theory, you could use a third-party tool such as [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403510/9146820) post for more details.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate that.

Comment: @kylefoley76 If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it for broader visibility and for the benefit of the community.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'accept for broader visibility'.  If you mean upvote it, then I already did that. If you mean place a check mark under it then I've already done that too.